# Conversion for Hex to Float - Big Endian (ABCD) in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert this hex "46b76833" to float, and I need to get this value 23476.1

I written a code to get hex and everything else but this step I don't know how to do, can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
function hexToFloat(hex) {
    var s = hex >> 31 ? -1 : 1;
    var e = (hex >> 23) & 0xFF;
    var rez = s * (hex & 0x7fffff | 0x800000) * 1.0 / Math.pow(2, 23) * Math.pow(2, (e - 127));
    return rez
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, we just need to convert the hex string to a number before we tranform to a float.

The MSB is the sign, the following 8 bits are the exponent, then the last 23 bits represent the fraction of the number.

This is an IEEE Single Precision floating point number, there are more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

```js
function hexStringToFloat(hexString) {
    const hex = parseInt(hexString, 16);
    const sign = hex >> 31 ? -1 : 1;
    const exponent = (hex >> 23) & 0xFF;
    return sign * (hex & 0x7fffff | 0x800000) * 1.0 / Math.pow(2, 23) * Math.pow(2, (exponent - 127));
}

console.log("Result:", hexStringToFloat("46b76833"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! So I only missed the parseInt converter, you made my day!

Comment: Great, glad to be of help!!